# How to update many to many relationship in Entity Framwork with lots of data

Tags: sql, entity-framework, many-to-many, insert-update

There are already a lot of questions on stackoverflow about how to update a many-to-many relationship with Entity Framework but all of these use only 2-3 records (e.g. a user and two or three roles).

In the answers you see the usage of `.Include()` when loading an entity.

But how do I update a relationship when there could be huge amounts of records like 50.000 `TYPE1`s and 10.000 `TYPE2`s. It can't be very performant to load a `TYPE1` with its 20.000 `TYPE2`s just to add one more `TYPE1` to it (or vice versa).

How would you do that with EF(6)?

EDIT:
We're working detached with ObjectContext and Model-First approach.

Comment: With large amounts of data you should access the junction table directly, maybe like [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45441/7251).

Comment: Create a stored procedure to do the update directly and add it to context store model, otherwise you'd have to load entire set of records to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to load the relationships using `.Include()` to add records.  If you're adding just one more relationship, or even a couple you can do the following:

Assuming you have a link table with no other columns:

```
Type1 aType1 = dbContext.Type1s.Find(<some type1 id>);

Type2 aType2 = dbContext.Type2s.Find(<some type2 id>);

aType1.Type2Collection.Add(aType2);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

That said, if your link table has additional columns then you you can do this:

```
Type1 aType1 = dbContext.Type1s.Find(<some type1 id>);

Type2 aType2 = dbContext.Type2s.Find(<some type2 id>);

TypeRelationships rel = new TypeRelationship()
{
Type1Id = aType1.Id,
Type2Id = aType2.Id,
// Other column values here
};

dbContext.TypeRelationships.Add(rel);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**Alternatively**, you can simply execute a raw SQL statement from your DbContext like so:

```
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [dbo].[TypeRelationships] (Type1Id, Type2Id) VALUES (type1Id, type2Id)");
```

**NOTE**: Make sure to use parameterised values when doing this, I merely show the method to execute.

**Lastly**, EF will execute a single query for each INSERT statement.  If you have 1000's to insert, consider using Table-Valued Parameters and raw ADO to execute a Stored Procedure.

Comment: Your first sample assumes I'm working with attached entities doesn't it? How does it change things when working detached and with ObjectContext instead of DbContext?

Comment: @JoDavid Hmm, OK I perhaps assumed that! :-) I'm no expert in that scenario, but does the following link help? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-many-to-many-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx